# Why is FFT of shape(200000,1) different from FFT of shape(200000,)?

Tags: numpy, fft

I am taking the FFT of optical OFDR ([1](https://www.anritsu.com/en-us/sensing-devices/guide/sls-example),[2](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=088e5323aeb8f18aJmltdHM9MTY5Mjc0ODgwMCZpZ3VpZD0zMmNjYTU3Yy1mYzczLTYzZTctMjE1NS1iNjIxZmQ5ZDYyMDMmaW5zaWQ9NTM3NQ&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=32cca57c-fc73-63e7-2155-b621fd9d6203&psq=ofdr+explanation&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9udHJzLm5hc2EuZ292L2FwaS9jaXRhdGlvbnMvMjAyMzAwMDUyNjkvZG93bmxvYWRzL05BU0EtVFAtMjAyMzAwMDUyNjkucGRmP2F0dGFjaG1lbnQ9dHJ1ZQ&ntb=1),[3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/optical-frequency-domain-reflectometry)) data from a commercial instrument.

However I spent days confused by why the FFT was not giving the expected result. Turned out it was because the array I'd imported had shape `(20000,1)` instead of `(20000,)`.  The FFT of the former `(20000,1)` comes back unchanged, whereas the FFT of an object with shape `(20000,)` produces the correct result.
Conceptually these seem like exactly the same array to me - but in practice they are apparently different FFT calculations.

Can anyone explain *why* this seemingly imaginary dimension broke my FFT?

```
# Produces bad FFT:
>> np.shape(MeasData)
: (433229, 1)

# Produces correct FFT
>> np.shape(MeasData[:,0])
: (433229,)
```

And 2ndly what does it mean to have an empty dimension?  That is, why is shape reported as `(2000,)` instead of `(2000)` (no comma)?

Here is a a plot showing each of these and the corresponding Fourier Transform, taken via `numpy.rfft( MeasData )`  (Sorry I don't know how to generate useful MWE data):
[image: MeasData and FFT plots]

The 1st & 2nd (MeasData = [433000,1]) shows that the FFT did nothing at all, while the 3rd & 4th (MeasData = [433000,]) shows the correct FFT.

How does that make sense that a shape `[400000,1]` is different from `[400000,]`? Seems pretty counterintuitive.

Comment: That's not an empty dimension. A shape of `(2000,)` has no second dimension. `(2000)` would just be an int in grouping parentheses, so the trailing comma is needed to indicate that this is a tuple.

Comment: You can think of shape [n] representing a 1D array - i.e. [1,2,3,4...] and [n,m] being a n x m 2D array (i.e. matrix) i.e. [[1,2],[3,4]...]. Now you can have a matrix that is [n,1] or [1,m] but they're not exactly the same as an array since you still need to index both the row and column despite the fact that one or the other is always unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `numpy.fft.rfft` computes an FFT over the last dimension of the input. When you pass it an array of shape `(20000, 1)`, it computes 20000 FFTs of 1-element vectors, rather than treating the input as a 20000-element vector to compute a single FFT of.

NumPy is an n-dimensional array library, not a matrix library. A 2-dimensional array with a length-1 second dimension is considered completely different from a 1-dimensional array. If you want to represent a vector, you should almost always represent it as a 1-dimensional array. The `(20000,)`-shape array is 1-dimensional.

Comment: I see - thinking of numpy as an n-dimensional package helps - so an array with shape `(2000,1)` is actually a 2D array, but just happens to have a single "column" if you will.

Comment: Ok, here's a way to illustrate my mistake. The erroneous 2-D array:
`>> np.shape(  np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])  )` --> `(5, 1)`, so `np.fft()` would calc 5 single-element FFT's; versus `np.shape(  np.array([1,2,3,4,5])  )`--> `(5,)` which is a real 1-D array, producing correct FFT.